# mapping extra mouse buttons

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, mouse

I have SteelSeries Sensei mouse with extra buttons: 8 9 10 11.
I want to map them as follows:
8: Shift_L, 9: CTRL_L, 10: PAGE_DOWN, 11: PAGE_UP

I spent hours looking for solutions.

problems with xbindkeys(best option):
Shift and Ctrl: no key down, key up. example:
typing, mouse 8 down, typing, mouse 8 up, typing. result:
test TEST TEST.
no hold repeat: mouse 10 down and hold, produces PageDown only once.

problems with imwheel:
could not make 10 and 11 work.
binds different actions to software - I don't need that mess.

I just want  mouse btn 10 === PageDown key, can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do will not work as:

- for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>: You cannot bind mouse-down and mouse-up events to key-press and key-up events only to keys...
- for the <kbd>PgDn</kbd>: Mouse buttons don't have a repeat function: only mouse-down and mouse-up (no "mouse-repeat")

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news (but at least, you will not be losing any more time with it...)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you try **Input Remapper** software. They provide a GUI and even several buttons in my mouse which didn't register any clicks `xbindkeys` showed up in this application.

You can find the software in the Software Center or App Center or use this [link](https://linuxhint.com/input-remapper-linux/) to install it through the terminal.

[image: input-remapper-screenshot]