# How can I run my gaming mouse firmware on Ubuntu?

Tags: mouse, games, firmware

I have a steel series gaming mouse with some extra buttons on the side. When I was using windows, I could use the steel series firmware to customize the behavior of the buttons. One feature in particular which was useful for me was making it so that while I held down right click on my mouse, it would spam right clicks at a specific rate. I installed ratbagd and piper, but it seems that they don't support such a feature. Is there any way I can get the steel series firmware to run on Ubuntu, and if I can't do that, is there any way I could use something else to customize my mouse inputs like this?

Comment: You can refer to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1456923/1450948) for customizing your mouse extra buttons